# Android widget Text to Speech not speaking

Tags: android, android-widget, text-to-speech

I referred to two links:

- [Android Homescreen Widgets- Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html)
- [starting text to speech engine from a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100246/starting-text-to-speech-engine-from-a-service)

From these two links, I created an AppWidgetProvider class and a Service class like so:

```
public class HomeWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            HomeWidget.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), VoiceService.class);
    homeIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
    context.startService(homeIntent);
    }
}
```

the service:

```
public class VoiceService extends Service implements OnInitListener{
public static TextToSpeech mtts;
private static final String LOG = "VoiceService";
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG,"Service created successfully!");
    mtts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),this);
    mtts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
     if(mtts!=null)
      {
         mtts.stop();
         Log.d(LOG,"The service has been destroyed!");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
            .getApplicationContext());

    int[] allWidgetIds = intent
            .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
            HomeWidget.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
    Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

    for(int widgetId : allWidgetIds)
    {
        Log.w(LOG,"inside for loop");
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
                .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                R.layout.home_widget);
        mtts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),this);
        mtts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
        mtts.speak("This is the text to be spoken", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),HomeWidget.class);
        clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.home, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    stopSelf();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I got the widget up and when I tap the widget, these 6 lines in logcat appears:

```
08-03 02:12:55.354: D/VoiceService(3666): Service created successfully!
08-03 02:12:55.358: W/VoiceService(3666): From Intent1
08-03 02:12:55.358: W/VoiceService(3666): Direct1
08-03 02:12:55.358: W/VoiceService(3666): inside for loop
08-03 02:12:55.358: I/TTS received:(3666): This is the text to be spoken
08-03 02:12:55.370: D/VoiceService(3666): The service has been destroyed!
```

But I'm not hearing anything. I've maxed the volume, ensured that it was using a speech synthesis engine(Pico TTS) and installed both English(United States) and English(United Kingdom) for it. I've also installed voice data required for speech synthesis.

What else am I missing or doing wrong such that there isn't a voice being spoken?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the initial callback before sending any text to the tts because the constructor is an asynchronous operation that returns before it is ready you speak. Move the call to speak either into the onInit call or something that is called from onInit.